# abas-ERP: Command in user menu for specific screen priority

Tags: erp, abas

I need a command which calls a screen in a specific priority.
In detail:
I'd like to offer a menu entry to our users were they can simple change the work day calendar in employee data sets and nothing else. I know the correct way would be creating a lower prio screen and grand the user such prio for accessing employees. But these users are allowed to change more than the work day calendar! I just like to reduce the fields in screen for a more simple recording and maintaining of absence from work.
So they should be able to view and change the normal employee screen but with a special command (from command view) the should open the same employee but with reduced number of field. Simple: separated screens for different use cases.

I believe I have to solve it by providing a service program in infosystem or similar but I'd like to ask you for a better way of solution before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can work with different screen context modes.
Please keep in mind, that screen modes works just within new screen descriptions.

(almost) Every element in the screen editor has an option called visibility scope (Sichbarkeit -> Geltungsbereich)

[image]

For example you could define a scope called EXTENDEDPERMISSION.
Then the element would be only visible, when you set the screencontext in FO to "EXTENDEDPERMISION"

```
..: set one screen context
.formula P|maskkontextfop = "EXTENDEDPERMISION"
..
..: set some screen contexts
.formula P|maskkontextfop = "VIEW1 VIEW2 LIGHTVIEW"
```

You can set the screen context in every event you'd like to.
For more infos you can search for "maskkontextfop" in the online help.

**But keep in mind, that the user still can access all variables over the dynamic selection as long as you grant them the permission to these fields!**

So if you really want, that a user (under no circumstances) gains access to some fields, you'll have to configure the right permissions.

Comment: Okay thank you! It's a **very** good explanation of the screen context. By the way it's the way i  have chosen for my solution! =)
But I think it would be great to define different scopes if you have very different use cases.